# .mov files into an NSArray

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

i have put in a method that creates a thumbnail image of the video for me

```
- (UIImage *)loadImage:(NSString *)image
{
    // getting the frame of the video for the thumbnail
    NSString *videoPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:image ofType:nil];
    NSURL *vidURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:videoPath];
    AVURLAsset *asset = [[AVURLAsset alloc ] initWithURL:vidURL options:nil];
    AVAssetImageGenerator *generate = [[AVAssetImageGenerator alloc] initWithAsset:asset];
    NSError *err = NULL;
    CMTime time = CMTimeMake(1, 30);
    CGImageRef thumbImg = [generate copyCGImageAtTime:time actualTime:NULL error:&err];

    return [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:thumbImg];
}
```

now i have a list of .mov files i wish to place into an array and place the thumbnail images of each into cells then once the cell has been touched it will go to detailedViewController and the .mov will start to play automatically.

my question is how do i put the .mov files into an array, and if i do that one of the parameters in the method above need to be (NSArray *) right ? yes/no and also could you help me on making the file play in the detailedViewController what do i need AVFoundation MPMoviePlayerController.

thanks

Comment: Don't store media file into array, instead of store media file url paths.

Comment: could you point me in the right direction of an example

Comment: This question needs a lot of improvement.  The posted code sample is completely irrelevant and has nothing to do with the problem.  The code snippet is for generating thumbnails from a video, and you didn't mention a problem with this.  You listed out what you need to do, didn't really tell us what you've tried and what specific problems you've run into that actually relate to your general problem of just not having a clue what you're doing.  What you need is a tutorial, and you can find one on google just as easy as anyone else.

Comment: just needed some help not some fool thinking he'e the man

Comment: What does 'placing .mov files into an array' mean?  I hope he doesn't literally mean to save all entire video files in an array.  And what he ultimately wants to know is how to play back just as nhgrif suggests.  So he asks two questions under one topic.  (1) how to save whatever in an array.  (2) how to play back video.

Answer (score 1):

Make list of video **url** instead of **.mov** files.

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier=@"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if (cell==nil) {
         cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
    }
    cell.imageView.image=[self loadImage:[arrVideoPath objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    return cell
}
```

Comment: how do i make the url im trying to look on the net but i cant find it i have 31 videos i have put them into a folder in my project i just need to see an example to understand how it works

Comment: NSString *stringPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"FOLDER_NAME" ofType:nil];
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:stringPath];

Comment: not use folder name use video name NSString *strVideo1=[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"video1" ofType:@"mp4"];NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:strVideo1];

Comment: but i have more than one video i would like to display in the cells

Comment: i want the thumbnails of the videos so i can display them in the cell

Comment: but i dont know how to get the video path for the videos

Comment: take one array and all the string (like strVideo1,strVideo2..so on) of the video in array. and then use above method in cellForRowAtIndexPath

Comment: otherwise give me a project i will make it for you